# MongoDB active status failed

Tags: nginx, mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

My server running on Nginx Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I want to install mongoDB to use it with node.js then I followed this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mongodb-on-ubuntu-16-04) but when I write the status command I have this.

```
● mongodb.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-07-26 20:21:15 CEST; 7s ago
  Process: 4527 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=14)
 Main PID: 4527 (code=exited, status=14)

Jul 26 20:21:15 ns3039456.ip-94-23-252.eu systemd[1]: Started High-performance, schema-free document-oriented d
Jul 26 20:21:15 ns3039456.ip-94-23-252.eu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status
Jul 26 20:21:15 ns3039456.ip-94-23-252.eu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jul 26 20:21:15 ns3039456.ip-94-23-252.eu systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Do you have any solution to fix my problem ? If you have a solution who need to completly remove mongodb it's ok. I have nothing in my database because this is my first installation.

I tried this command to remove mongodb :

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
```

But I have this error

```
E: Unable to locate package mongodb.service
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'mongodb.service'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'mongodb.service'
```

But I did like as the tutorial said. I created the `mongo.service` files inside `/etc/systemd/system`

**Edit :**

With the mongod command I have this :

```
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6201 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=ns3039456.ip-94-23-252.eu
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.8
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: ed70e33130c977bda0024c125b56d159573dbaf0
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1404
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-07-26T20:54:46.024+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-07-26T20:54:46.056+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-07-26T20:54:46.056+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Comment: The error message was very explicit about what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self-explanatory, file `/etc/mongodb.conf` is missing on your system, so you need to create one.
This simple config will allow you to start `mongod`

```
systemLog:
 verbosity: 1
 quiet: true
 traceAllExceptions: false
 path: "/opt/mongo/log/local.log"
 logAppend: true
 destination: file
storage:
 dbPath: "/opt/mongo/db"
 journal:
  enabled: true
processManagement:
 fork: true
net:
 port: 27017
security:
 authorization: disabled
```

Just set appropriate path for logs/storage and ensure that `mongod` is able to write there.

Comment: My bad I was wrong about my command line `/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongodb.conf` I tried with mongod.conf and it works. So the main problem is on the first error in my question about `Active: failed`

Comment: `Active: failed` just means that the mongodb process failed to start. Take a look at the mongodb application log. Most likely you need to fix permissions or create dbpath.